# Query and display thousands of features using PostGIS and WMS?

Tags: postgis, wms

We have a feature table in PostgreSQL with PostGIS plugin, the table contains almost 200 thousand points.

In the application, we need to query features according to different conditions (for example inside an irregular polygon or rectangle or name contains some keywords) and then display all the features in the map. However, the matched result may contain thousands of points or more, so add the in the front by something like `marker` is unacceptable, so rendering in the server maybe a good choice.

I have thought about WMS, however I am not sure if it can fit the requirement.

I wonder if there is a better choice?

Comment: Yes wms will be fine,

Comment: What is your goal? If you want to have the points as features in you rapplication the WMS is not the way to go, as it delivers only a picture. If your WMS is really what you want you need a Server like UMN MapServer or Geoserver or others for it. An in this Server you set your connection to the db and the queries.

Comment: Does wms support filters like spatial and attribute filters?

Comment: You can use bounding boxes to restrict what is shown spatially, and you can use external SLD to filter out points according to their attributes. You can click on a point and retrive information about the points in that location.

Answer (score 2):

WMS do support the filter (EQUALS, DISJOINT, INTERSECTS, TOUCHES, CROSSES, WITHIN, CONTAINS, OVERLAPS, RELATE, DWITHIN ) and openlayer-3 or 2 can reload the wms images according to filter refer

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html